# Nested for-loop output

Tags: java, loops

I'm learning about Java loops and struggling to understand how an output was produced for a question regarding nested-for loops.

The code is:

```
for(int count = 0; count <=3; count++)
    for(int count2 = 0; count2 < count; count2++)
        System.out.println(count2);
```

The output produced was:

> 0
>   0
>   1
>   0
>   1
>   2

Can anyone please explain this as there isn't an explanation in the book like there usually is, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First loop variable: Count is looping to 3.

second loop variable: count2 is looping to count.

then you are printing the count 2. so first time you print nothing because 0 is not less then 0, and therefore stop right away because in that iteration count2 is not less then count. then count becomes 1, and at the time you are printing. Therefore you print 0. You follow this logic until count is <= 3, and count2 < count.

Here is a table that iterates through the loop: Hope this helped.
[image: Here is a table that iterates through the loop.]

Comment: yea its much easier to visualize with the table. I use to be a teacher assistant in my intro to CS class at my university, and found it easier to explain loops with tables. :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. It made it easier for me to understand. I wasn't aware the count for count2 would reset when the boolean expression for the nested-loop evaluated to false. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple,Read this as

```
for(int count = 0; count <=3; count++) {
    for(int count2 = 0; count2 < count; count2++) {
        System.out.println(count2);
     }
}
```

So when outer loop is 0,
inner loop will run 0 times as count2

So when outer loop is 1,
inner loop will run 1 times as count2<1 and hence it will run one time then count2 is incremented and so will fail and hence 0 as output

and similarly output continues till count is 3

Answer (score 0):

Looking at

```
for (int count = 0; count <= 3; count++) 
{
    for (int count2 = 0; count2 < count; count2++)
    {
        System.out.println (count2); 
    }
}
```

You first enter the loop with `count = 0;`. Then the inner loop will not execute, since the initial condition is wrong (`count2 < count` is false since `0 < 0 = false`). Then `count`increases by one. The inner loop will then print all values which are strictly smaller than the outer loop variable (`count`). So if `count = 1` the inner loop will print all numbers starting from 0 which are strictly smaller than 0, i.e. only 0 in that case. For `count = 2`, it will print `0,1` since these numbers are all strictly smaller than `count`. Same for `count = 3`, it prints the numbers 0,1,2. And that produces the output.

```
 <No output from count = 0>
 0 <from count = 1>
 0 
 1  <from count = 2>
 0  
 1
 2  <from count = 3>
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand this code change your code to following -

```
for (int count = 0; count <= 3; count++) {
    for (int count2 = 0; count2 < count; count2++) {
        System.out.print(count2 + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This will produce output as -

> 0
>   0 1
>   0 1 2

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code would be clearer with curly braces and indentation :

```
for (int count = 0; count <=3; count++) {
    for (int count2 = 0; count2 < count; count2++) {
        System.out.println (count2);
    }
}
```

Now the outer for loop will iterate 4 times with `count` getting values 0,1,2,3

the inner loop won't iterate for `count == 0` so nothing is printed. For the values of `count`, `count2` will be :

[image]

which explains the result you are getting